# UIViewController placement on screen

Tags: swift, xcode, screen, viewcontroller

I have created a simple app for my school classes and everything works great apart from the app loading in the middle of the screen.

centre screen
[image: centre screen]

I would like it to appear here!

bottom of screen
[image: bottom of screen]

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

Click on your Window Controller Scene and then on Window
you will se in the Size Inspector a windows which is changeable and then you can move your Window as you wish. **Important is to fix your position** like in the image :

[image]